# my xml file is loaded into swf but not loaded when I embed swf into html page

Tags: xml, html, flash

my xml file is loaded into swf but not loaded when I embed  swf into html page
any help?

```
var data1:XML = new XML();
data1.ignoreWhite=true;
data1.load("foods.xml");

data1.onLoad = function(success){
if (success){
    name_txt.text = data1.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.name;
    count_txt.text = data1.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.count;
    type_txt.text = data1.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.type;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Guess №1:** you are testing this from the local folder and facing security issues. You can fix that by adding your working folder to the list of trusted locations: https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html **Guess №2:** Relative URLs are loaded relatively to top HTML frame location, not relatively to SWF location.

Comment: And it's a good practice to declare the onLoad listener before you call the .load() method - when the file is cached it might happen that your file loads before the loader knows what to do onLoad.

Comment: Also check where the swf is trying to load the file from - just open the developer console (F12 in chrome and firefox), goto Network and refresh your page. You will see either a red failed request to XML (wrong file location) or no request at all (security issue). If the file is not loaded locally but over http you might need to create or change the crossdomain.xml file on your server